# Changing android:minSdk in already published App in Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, google-play

When I first upload the app, I published the app in hurry and had 14 as minSdk in manifest file, however practically the app is compatible with 3.0(11), which I now realized so now my users are pretty less.

My question is can I downgrade the android:minsdk in manifest now and publish an update in order to target a larger audience?

Comment: publish an update for your app by changing the minSDK version in manifest

Comment: update the application version and change the SDK version as you want.

Comment: @Auto-Droidツ will there be two app one for API 14 and one for API11 or there will be just one ?

Comment: @Saty as the package name will be the same it will override the uploaded apk all you got to do is just change the version and minSDK in manifest

Comment: if you apply update then there will only be one application for example. first you published it as version 1 but you made some changes and updated the version as 1.2 then there will be only one application with version 1.2 available on market with the changes you made. in your case you will only change minSDK which will make it available to more devices

Answer (score 4):

Just publish the same app with a new `android:minSdkVersion` and with a higher version code (i.e. `android:versionCode`) than the one currently on Google Play, then uploaded to Google Play, and you're good to go.